# How to group and count value of item in array

Tags: aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    providers: [
      {
        code: 1
      },
      {
        code: 1
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    providers: [
      {
        code: 2
      },
      {
        code: 1
      },
      {
        code: 2
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I have documents like that

And want to get the result like:

```
[
  {
    "code": 1,
    "total": 2 (because it appear in two item of the array)
  },
  {
    "code": 2,
    "total": 1 (because it appear in just the second item of the array)
  }
]
```

I've try to unwind the array and group with the $sum: 1 but when unwind, the total will be increased and that's not I want. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You had a good idea, you just needed to transform your `code` array to set with `$setIntersection`.

See on mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/NwVcO9iBXAf

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      providers: {
        "$setIntersection": "$providers"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$providers"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$providers.code",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      code: "$_id",
      total: "$count"
    }
  }
])
```